# Prevent malicious attacks on Online Judge software

Tags: java, security

I have an ACM Online Judge based on Windows XP.

Now I have encouraged a problem that people submit shutdown code to my Server.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime tr = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        tr.exec("shutdown -s -f -t 60");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any good ideas?**The simple, the better.**

Comment: When we participated in ACM competitions, sending a fork bomb, trying to steal the test harness, or causing the judges headaches got you kicked out.  I'd solve this with policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be running submitted Java code in a Java sandbox with a [security manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) that forbids things like:

- running external commands,
- calling System.exit(),
- accessing the file system,
- opening sockets,
- creating threads,
- and anything else that is going to cause you grief.

But even that is insufficient to deal with all possible concerns.  For example, it is really difficult to deal with resource hogging; e.g. creating lots of objects, using lots of CPU.  And you've got the problem of what happens if someone manages to break out of the sandbox, due to a mistake on your part ... or a Java security flaw.

If you don't feel confident that you understand all of the issues, **your best option** is (IMO) to shut down your "judge".  It is (IMO) an unnecessary high risk activity.

Comment: Thanks,It works. One more question: If I use "java -DsecurityManager test" to prevent the attack.  I wonder if there is some great code get SecurityException.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). Defining you own SecurityManager will allow you to restrict what the code can do by specifying a [policy file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html).

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/index.html) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the java-sandbox project [1] which aims at making it easy to customize security managers for running untrusted code. It makes it relatively easy to define exactly what resources should be accessible.

[1] http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/the-java-sandbox.html